# How to change column formatting of regression results in flextable?

Tags: r, formatting, regression, glm, flextable

I have created a flextable object of my GML modeling results. However, the p-values are shown as zeros because they are very small. I would like to show them in e/scientific format but don't know how to access certain column and change the number formatting. Do you know how to do that?

Here's the table that flextable produced:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `colformat_double()`.

```r
lmod <- lm(rating ~ complaints + privileges +
             learning + raises + critical, data=attitude)
ft <- as_flextable(lmod)
ft |> 
  colformat_double(j = "p.value", digits = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! This helps a bit, but I still cannot change the formatting rule to scientific. I found a function format() which has an argument scientific=TRUE but don't understand if it's possible to use it with colformat_double()?

Comment: EDIT: got it working with this ft_glm  %>% 
  set_formatter("p.value" = function(x) {
    formatC(x, format = "e", digits = 2)
  })